# Recover from using bad code page in C#

Tags: c#, unicode, character-encoding, codepages

I have read string "ńîôč˙" from file by using code page windows-1251, instead of using iso-8859-2. It should be some Cyrillic string. How to implement function that will do following in C#:

```
string res = Recover("ńîôč˙");

string Recover(string input)
{
    ???
}
```

Where res is Cyrillic string that I would have got if I used good page when reading file in first place.

Comment: How do you plan on identifying when the encoding is incorrect?

Comment: I was looking string in debug, and this works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Off the top of my head..

```
string Recover(string input)
{
   return Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-2").GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(input));
}
```

Comment: Ah! It wasn't an error on my behalf then, it was me copying from the question :)

Comment: Heh, i tried that, but error was not in procedure, I did not know original encoding and I assumed wrong one. My case was 1251 -> 1250 ;(

Answer (score 4):

You can use the methods of the `System.Text.Encoding` class:

```
using System.Text;
using System;

class EncodingConverter
{
    static string ConvertEncoding(string input, 
        Encoding srcEncoding, 
        Encoding targetEncoding)
    {
        byte[] buffer = srcEncoding.GetBytes(input);
        return targetEncoding.GetString(buffer);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = args[0];
        string converted = ConvertEncoding(input, 
            Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250"), 
            Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-2"));
        Console.WriteLine(converted);
    }
}
```